# load JSON data in dynamically generated script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, performance

I was just experimenting with some javascript, browsing the web for fast search on the client side. I came accross [this](http://code.flickr.net/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/) link where blogger briefly mentions loading data as an executable script by wrapping it in a callback function.

Even though this might not be the best way to do it, can someone explain how this might actually work?

I have been trying the following code in the head section.

```
<script id="jsonD" type="application/json" src="/data/catalogEntries.json"></script>
```

I can see in the dev tools that the file is being transferred. But I can't figure out how to use the data in another script.

I also tried the following at the end of the body section.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'application/json';
            script.src = '/data/catalogEntries.json';
            head.appendChild(script);
        })
```

I am also trying to find out how I can measure the time it takes for the browser to parse the data and compare it with a plain use of eval(). The data that I have is more than 4k Kilobytes.

I know I can do this using XMLHttpRequests and I have done this multiple times but this seemed like a much faster way of parsing a large amount of data based on the blog link that I posted earlier.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Paras

**UPDATE**

Here is a plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/C2N0Wc4XZCnS5aD4hErY?p=preview

Comment: Check out [this article](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html).

Comment: I did a lot of research and this is the first thing I found. I still don't understand from this article, how to access the data that might be loaded and parsed.

Comment: Just added a plunker. May be this will make it easier to try out what I am talking about.

Comment: *a plain use of eval()* — We've had `JSON.parse()` for a very long time now. Don't use `eval()`.